# How to remove selected items from dropdown list checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using this bootstrap dropdown list to select by using checkboxes, all fine just want to add in success after create new record to remove the selected items and keep them unselected.

```
             <select class="test" name="roles[]" id="roles" multiple>
              <option value="1">item1</option>
               <option value="2">item2</option>
              <option value="3">item3</option>       
             </select>
```

Jquery:

```
     $('#SubmitCreateForm').click(function(e) {    
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: $('#archiveurl').attr('href'),
            method: 'post',
            data: $("#createform").serialize(),

            success: function(result) {
                     $('#roles').find('option').remove().end(); // I tried this but not work!      
                }
            }
        });
     });
```

Im using this plugin for this type of checkboxes in dropdownlist

https://github.com/mgibbs189/fSelect

[image]

Comment: Can you frame your question little better so that it's understandable?

Comment: Please post your javascript.

Comment: do you mean just uncheck the checkboxes? or is remove all elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are not *really* checkboxes *!* but `select option`, so you can unselect like below:

```js
window.fs_test = $('.test').fSelect();

//

$('#button').click(function() {
  $('#roles option').prop('selected', false)
  $('.fs-option').removeClass('selected')
});
```

```css
select {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://facetwp.com/wp-content/plugins/facetwp/assets/vendor/fSelect/fSelect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://facetwp.com/wp-content/plugins/facetwp/assets/vendor/fSelect/fSelect.css">
<select class="test" name="roles[]" id="roles" multiple>
  <option value="1" selected>item1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>item2</option>
  <option value="3" selected>item3</option>
</select>

<button id="button">Uncheck</button>
```

**Updated:**

As you mentioned which plugin you are using, After I checked, can say there is no native way to uncheck selected, it's not advanced plugin, kinda weak! it even not support `attr` data from native element, so I did the trick, remove `selected` class from list.

```
$('.fs-option').removeClass('selected')
```

Comment: this is not working for me, Im using this plugin from this link
https://github.com/mgibbs189/fSelect

Comment: this is work yes like this:                            $('.fs-option').removeClass('selected');
                           $('.fs-label').html('Select options'); but this in view but actually it still select the old values

Comment: @Ash use this too `$('#roles option').attr('selected', false)`

Comment: I still have problem if I used $('#roles').find('option').remove().end(); will remove the selected options  but if I tried to add new one and selected roles again then will keep the selections empty, this one $('#roles option').attr('selected', false) doesnt remove the selected items

Comment: this one is working fine, $('#roles').find('option').remove().end();    but the problem if im in the same page and wanted to add new user with some roles, it will keep it unselected even in the view show them selected!!!!

Comment: @Ash `$('#roles option').prop('selected', false)`

Comment: sir,   $('#roles option').prop('selected') this one still keep it selected even it shows no item is selected, thats why I can't use it

Comment: @Ash as you see in my snippet, it's working fine, it select (checkbox) and unselect in a same time. I can not detect without a live example of your code

Comment: here its working amazing like this:                              $('#roles option').prop('selected', false);
                           $('.fs-option').removeClass('selected');
                           $('.test').fSelect('reload');

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
success: function(result) {
   $('#roles').find('option').remove().end(); // I tried this but not work!      
}
```

You don't specify which "option" you want to delete. Try this:

```
$("#roles option[value='X']").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get removed the selected option from a  tag apply remove() function on the selected option: $("#roles").children('option:selected').remove();

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#roles").on('change',function(){
    $(this).children('option:selected').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select class="test" name="roles[]" id="roles" multiple>
              <option value="1">item1</option>
               <option value="2">item2</option>
              <option value="3">item3</option>
             </select>
</body>

</html>
```